The difference between conditional and unconditional models when developing a longitudinal mediation latent growth curve analysis
I was just wondering if anyone could advise me on what the definition of an unconditional and conditional model when you are taking a stepwise approach to developing a mediational latent growth curve model? In my model I am looking to see whether the latent factors mediate the relationship between a time invariant predictor and a time invariant outcome variable.
Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
